# Automatic add marker on Google Maps from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've followed [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) to plot markers from a database on my GMaps page. I have 2 type of markers (Green: marker status on my DB equals zero; Red: marker status on my database equals one) and I need to update the marker icon everytime a change is made on DB status column. I also want to adapt this code to add markers on map everytime I got a new line on my DB. The question is that I can't refresh the entire page, I'm allowed to refresh only the markers.

Someone know a way to do this? I'm using MySQL, PHP and JavaScript on my page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will have to use AJAX to do this. You can load the map via AJAX, and use `setInterval()` to reload the map and show the changes. In this way you are not reloading the page, you can reload just the contents of a `<div>` with the map's contents.